# How to split a file into irregular parts between the starting and ending indexes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I would like to split a file into 3 smaller files. Unfortunately, I can't do it in equal pieces because I can't have the same unique values from column `A` in two different files. That's why I get the end indexes in a given piece of file as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('ex_1.xls')

x = []
for id, df_i in  enumerate(np.array_split(df, 3)):

    df2 = df[df['A'] == df_i['A'][-1:].to_string(index=False).strip()][-1:]
    x.append(df2.index[0])

print(x) 

Example output x: 
[15, 67, 122]
```

This means that the first file should contain dataframe values from `df` between indexes 1 and 15, the second file between 16 and 67, and the third file between 68 and 122. Of course, each file must have headers from the main `df` dataframe. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Do you not know how to select rows by position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can add first value, then `zip` with add `1` for indexes and select in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
x = [15, 67, 122]
y = np.insert(x, 0, 0)
print (y)
[  0  15  67 122]

dfs = [df.loc[s:e] for s, e in zip(y + 1, y[1:])]
```